Reconstructing operator from action on orthonormal basis
I'm dealing with the following operator (U) on $L^2[0,\pi]$ acting in the following way on the basis $\{\cos((n+\frac{1}{2})x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$:
\begin{equation}
U\cos((n+\frac{1}{2})x) = \sin((n+\frac{1}{2})x)
\end{equation}
The action seems "pretty simple" to me and I wish if I can find a "nice" general form of the operator like $Uf = g$. I have tried writing a series expansion of the form $Uf = \sum_{n} \langle f , \psi_n \rangle U\psi_n$ where $\psi_n = cos((n+\frac{1}{2})x)$ but have come to nothing.
Thank you for any help and suggestion.

The set ${\cos ((n + \tfrac{1}{2})\cdot ) : n\in\mathbb{N} }$ does not span $L^{2}[0, \pi ]$ and it is also not an orthonormal set. At best you can scale this set to form an orthonormal set and describe what the linear operator is doing on the closed subspace spanned by that set.
